# Wiring template form actions with Python code

Tags: zope

I'm working on a website that has a “Sign up” page which should be callable from anywhere in the site.

I have the following dummy interface and implementation for the “user” product:

Interface:

```py
 ##
 ## located in bahmanm/sampleapp/interfaces.py
 ##
 class ISampleAppUser(Interface):
        """
        """
```

Implementation:

```py
 ##
 ## located in bahmanm/sampleapp/implementation/SampleAppUser.py
 ##
 class SampleAppUser:
      """
      """

      implements(ISampleAppUser)

 # Note that this method is outside of the implementation class.
 #
 def manage_addSampleAppUser(self, id, title):
    # ...
```

Now, for the moment, let's assume there's a link on the `index` page which leads to the following template (Sign up template):

```html
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal">
   <head><title>Add a new User</title></head>
   <body>
    <h2>Add a user instance</h2>
    <form action="#" method="POST"
          tal:attributes="action python:'manage_addSampleAppUser'">
       <p>Id: <input type="text" name="id"/></p>
       <p>Title: <input type="text" name="title"/></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
    </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

However I haven't been able to find the right value for `action` property of the `form`; all I get is a “resource not found”.

Honestly, I believe it's a problem of understanding Zope's mechanisms on my side. I'd really appreciate any hints/clues on where should I go digging for the solution, `configure.zcml` or the implementation or the template itself.  TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to create a view for that; you can call a Product factory like that from a URL too, but it is not recommended.

With a view, you can combine the form and the code to create the new user in one place:

```py
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserPage
from sampleapp.implementation.SampleAppUser import manage_addSampleAppUser


class NewUserSignup(BrowserPage):
    def __call__(self):
        # called when the view is being rendered
        if 'submit' in self.request:
            # form was submitted, handle
            self.addUser()
        return self.index()  # render the template

    def addUser(self):
        # extract form fields from self.request.form
        # validation, error handling, etc.
        if someerror:
            self.error = 'Error message!'
            return

        user = manage_addSampleAppUser(self.context, id, title)
        # add things to this new user if needed

        # all done, redirect to the default view on the new user object
        self.request.response.redirect(user.absolute_url())
```

then register this view with something like:

```xml
<browser:page
    for="*"
    name="signup"
    class=".signup.NewUserSignup"
    template="signup.pt"
    permission="zope.public"
    />
```

When your new page is registered, the named `template` is added as a `index` attribute on your `NewUserSignup` class, so the `__call__` method can invoke it (`self.index()`) and return the results.

Because you combined the signup handling and the template together, you can now easily incorporate error handling. When someone loads the page for the first time `self.request.form` will be empty, but as soon as someone hits the submit button, you can detect this and call the `addUser` method.

That method can either create the user and then redirect away from this page, or set an error message and return, at which point the form is re-rendered.

This makes the `action` easy to set; you could just leave it empty, or you can set it to the current context URL plus the name of the view. Together, the template then becomes:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal">
   <head><title>Add a new User</title></head>
   <body>
    <h2>Add a user instance</h2>
    <div class="errormessage" tal:condition="view/error|nothing" tal:content="view/error">
        Conditional error message appears here
    </div>

    <form action="#" method="POST"
          tal:attributes="action string:${context/absolute_url}/@@${view/__name__}">
       <p>Id: <input type="text" name="id"
                      tal:attributes="value request/form/id|nothing" /></p>
       <p>Title: <input type="text" name="title"
                      tal:attributes="value request/form/title|nothing" /></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit"/>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note how the form inputs are pre-filled with existing data from the request as well, making it easier for your visitor to correct any errors they may have made.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Puts all I needed to understand this 'view' business in one place.  Thanks a million @Martijn.